# Calling data from outside of Chartjs code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chart.js

I want to do something like this using Chartjs code:

```
const chartData = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 18, 30, 45, 40, 33, 22, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 33, 45, 42, 55, 30];

const dataLine = {
  labels: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'kWh',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: **{chartData}**
    }
  ]
};
```

I can't figure out how to call chartData inside the Chartjs code in the `data:` section.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the below? Refer to [Chartjs Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

```
const chartData = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 18, 30, 45, 40, 33, 22, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 33, 45, 42, 55, 30];

const dataLine = {
  labels: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'kWh',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: chartData
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Ahh, that worked, can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you.

Comment: Please mark this answer as a solution to close this topic. Thanks!